# Docker Mysql + Spring Connection Refussed

Tags: java, mysql, spring, docker

i setup a Mysql Server via Docker and while Running my Microservices inside of my IDE everything worked fine and i was able to connect to my Database via

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://docker:3079/vetdb?useSSL=false
```

Now i wanted to Test-Deploy my Microservices via Docker

Docker-Compose

```html
version: '3'

services:
  vetdb:
    container_name: vetdb
    hostname: vetdb
    image: mysql:latest
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=vetdb
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
    ports:
      - 3079:3306
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql

  VET:
    hostname: ${VET_HOSTNAME}
    container_name: ${VET_HOSTNAME}
    image: openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
    ports:
      - "${VET_PORT}:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/dockervolumes/microservices/VET/tmp:/tmp"
      - "./jar:/jar"
    entrypoint:
      - "java"
      - "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom"
      - "-jar"
      - "/jar/${VET_JAR_NAME}.jar"
    depends_on:
      - vetdb
    links:
      - vetdb:vetdb
```

and therefore i changed the datasource url

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://vetdb:3079/vetdb?useSSL=false
```

Now when i  run `docker-compose up --build` i get `Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)`

Application.Properties

```html
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://vetdb:3079/vetdb?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root  
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.platform=mysql
```

Im fairly new to Docker and i hope here is somebody that can help me.
Sorry for my horrible english

Ty in advance

**EDIT**
Thanks to @David Maze for the Solution!
    spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://vetdb:3306/vetdb?useSSL=false

Docker Compose

```html
version: '3'

services:
  vetdb:
    container_name: vetdb
    hostname: vetdb
    image: mysql:latest
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=vetdb
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql

  VET:
    hostname: ${VET_HOSTNAME}
    container_name: ${VET_HOSTNAME}
    image: openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
    ports:
      - "${VET_PORT}:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/dockervolumes/microservices/VET/tmp:/tmp"
      - "./jar:/jar"
    entrypoint:
      - "java"
      - "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom"
      - "-jar"
      - "/jar/${VET_JAR_NAME}.jar"
    depends_on:
      - vetdb
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you connect between containers using their container names as host names, you have to use the port number the server is running on directly.  It doesn't matter if any ports have been published (`docker run -p`, Docker Compose `ports:` line); you'd use the *second* port number from these lines.

In your case that means using the standard MySQL port 3306 (even though you've published to a different port on the host)

```
jdbc:mysql://vetdb:3306/vetdb?useSSL=false
```

Comment: thank you very much! in the end i used `spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://vetdb:3306/vetdb?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
` to make it boot without exceptions :) could u maybe also tell me how i could optimaze my docker-compose file? is there anything i could improve? any best practices? its all new for me and i want to learn as much as possible